# How to extract id parameter from string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a URL as string :

```
urlString = https://play.com/details?id=blamore
```

How to get the `id` parameter from the given string ?

Comment: use `print (s.split('=')[1])` or `print (s.split('id=')[1])`

Comment: Take a look at python's string methods. That's how..

Comment: But if there are some `=`? I need to bind to `id`

Comment: See [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: Are you using any kind of web framework? If you are, it probably does this for you. If you're not, the `urllib` answer below is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way to to do this in Python 3 is to use the [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs 

url = 'https://play.com/details?id=blamore'

t = urlparse(url)
print(t)

d = parse_qs(t.query)
print(d)
```

**output**

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='play.com', path='/details', params='', query='id=blamore', fragment='')
{'id': ['blamore']}
```

The field names of the `ParseResult` should be self-explanatory, but please refer to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) for details.

From the [`urllib.parse.parse_qs` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)

> Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as a dictionary.
>   The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values
>   are lists of values for each name.

Comment: what if ID is part of the url?   `www.website.com/foo/bar/id-656/details`

Comment: @tikej In that case, this question (and my answer) aren't very relevant. But it may still be a good idea to to use `urllib.parse` module functions to get a clean path string from the URL. Once you have the path string you can use standard `str` methods to extract the ID. Eg, `[s[3:] for s in url.split("/") if s.startswith("id-")]` creates a 1 item list containing the ID if it exists, otherwise the list is empty. Or you can use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) module to extract the ID, which makes it easier to use a specific ID pattern, but it's a little slower.